# Java-8 stream - cast list of sub types to list of super types

Tags: java-8

I have the following stream:

```
final List<List<ScheduleContainer>> scheduleIntervalContainerOfCurrentDay = new ArrayList<>(
        unconfirmedScheduleIntervalContainersOfWeeks.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ScheduleIntervalContainer::getStartDate).reversed())
            .filter(s -> s.getStartDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay().isEqual(today.withTimeAtStartOfDay()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ScheduleIntervalContainer::getStartDate, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())).values());
```

and at the end I will cast from `List` of type `List<ScheduleIntervalContainer>` to `List` of type `List<ScheduleContainer>` (ScheduleIntervalContainer is a subtype of ScheduleContainer). Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can collect the items into lists of the more general type by specifying the type parameter to use for `toList`:

```
Collectors.<ScheduleContainer>toList()
```